# ActivatedRouteSnapshot returns empty object with respect to canactive authguard

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular5

my route

```
 { path: 'my-products/manage-products', component:ManageProductsComponent,canActivate:[AuthGuard], }
```

url generated by after searching parameters is like as below :

```
    http://localhost:4200/my-products/manage-products?include_available_params=1&key=title&value=dharmesh&inrange=1&page=1&show=&sort_by=
```

my authguard code:

```
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) 
   {
     this.currentPath = route.url[0].path; 
   }
```

my problem is sometime i got route.url empty after route gets populated with query parameters .

Comment: Maybe in canActivate guard ActivatedRouteSnapshot shows prev route params? Since new route is not activated yet.

Comment: thanks for reply i only get

RouterStateSnapshot {_root: TreeNode, url: "/?include_available_params=1&inrange=1&page=6&category=&manufacturer=&show=&sort_by=title&sort=asc"}

Comment: check here what i get  https://imageresize.org/image/8e829416-3234-4ce5-80c7-aa232b343711